# Add border on image without modify original (GD php)

Tags: php, gd

I would like to add bottom border of 10px height on bottom of every image WITHOUT resizing the original image.

Exemple: i have one jpg 300X200 px, i add black border of 10 px height on the bottom, my image is now 300X210 with black border.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to display the image in the browser? If yes, why not adding the border through HTML/CSS?

Comment: No is for social website, my users want to add the copyright on the bottom.

Comment: why not have 2 copies of the same image? one with border and one without

Answer (score 2):

Function drawBorder code looks wrong. Should be as follows:

```
function drawBorder(&$img, &$color, $thickness) {
  $x = ImageSX($img);
  $y = ImageSY($img);
  for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++)
    ImageRectangle($img, $i, $i, $x--, $y--, $color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample that will draw a border. I have used the `GET` variable to call the image.

If you for example put this code in your images folder, you can call `example.org/images/resize.php?path=image.jpg`, without modifying the original image. You can even use mod_rewrite (assuming you are using apache) to apply this filter.

However, this may affect the performance (doing it on the fly), so I recommend at least caching the images on the server, or just saving them to disk.

```
<?php 

$img = ImageCreateFromJPEG($_GET['path']); 

// Draw border 
$color_black = ImageColorAllocate($img, 0, 0, 0); 
drawBorder($img, $color_black, 10); 


// Output 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
ImageJPEG($img); 



// Draw a border 
function drawBorder(&$img, &$color, $thickness) 
{  
    $x = ImageSX($img); 
    $y = ImageSY($img); 

    for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++) 
        ImageRectangle($img, 0, 0, $x, $y--, $color_black); 
} 

?>
```